# Multi loop UPDATE/INSERT Table for selected rows with WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables like this:

Table1

```
DataS DataH DataO
001    101    ABA
003    101    ABC
001    101    AAB
001    105    BBA
002    102    ABB
002    102    ACA
```

Table2

```
DataS DataH DataO Result1 Result2 Result3
003   101   ABC
001   105   BBA
```

I'm trying to make a procedure with two input parameters: `@DataS`, `@DataH`. What procedure should do:

1. Select all records from Table1 `WHERE DataS=@DataS AND DataH=@DataH`.
2. For every selected row, check IF record exists in Table2 with the same three values `[DataS]` `[DataH]` `[DataO]`.
3. IF yes - UPDATE this row in Table2 (SET Result1 = (MyFunction), SET Result2 = (MyFunction), etc.)
4. IF no - INSERT this row with all parameters [DataS] [DataH] [DataO] [Result1] [Result2] [Result3]

So Table2 should looks like this after procedure executed:

Table2 (after update)

```
DataS  DataH DataO Result1 Result2 Result3
003    101   ABC   1.5     1.3     1.4
001    105   BBA   1.6     1.1     1.3
001    101   ABA   1.6     1.3     1.4
001    101   AAB   1.6     1.3     1.4
002    102   ABB   1.1     1.4     1.4
002    102   ACA   1.3     1.4     1.1
```

Is it possible to do it in one procedure? What is the best way (to keep also good efficiency)? Is it possible to do it with cte, or is there a better solution, some loop function?

```
DECLARE @ID int
SELECT @ID = (SELECT ID FROM Table2 WHERE DataS=@DataS AND DataH=@DataH AND DataO=@DataO)
IF EXISTS @ID
BEGIN
    --UPDATE Table2 SET Result1=... WHERE ID=@ID
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   --INSERT INTO Table2 (.....)
END
```

UPDATE:
I think the best solution is to use MERGE as Luis Cazares said (thanks), so I made new procedure like:

```
MERGE Table2 AS ex
USING x AS st
ON (x.DataS = st.DataSAND ex.DataO = st.DataO AND ex.DataH = st.DataH)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ex.Result1 = 9
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(DataS,DataH,DataO,Result1)
VALUES(st.DataS,st.DataH,st.DataO,9);
```

Looking so smart, but it's not working and than I red that MERGE is not support on old 2005 SQL Server which I use (starts from 2008). So I try CURSOR function as mkRabbani proposed and it works (thank you).

Comment: What attempts have you made so can? Can you show us the SQL and explain why it didn't work as you intended?

Comment: Be aware that your code might have problems if concurrency is involved. Everything can be done in one MERGE or INSERT/UPDATE set, no need to loop (SQL Server will do that behind the scenes).

Comment: Larnu, well, as you can see in the code above, I have inside statement DECLARE @ID... But I don't know how to loop it.

Comment: Luis Cazares, thank you for your suggestion.  I try MERGE function, but as I have 2005 sql server database version it's not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using CURSOR as defined below. Test values should be replaced with your function output.

```
DECLARE @DataS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @DataH VARCHAR(50)

SET @DataS  =  '003'
SET @DataH = '101'

DECLARE @DataS_T1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @DataH_T1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @DataO_T1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @DataS_T2 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @DataH_T2 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @DataO_T2 VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR 
FOR 
SELECT 
T1.DataH DataH_T1,T1.DataO DataO_T1,T1.DataS DataS_T1,
T2.DataH DataH_T2,T2.DataO DataO_T2,T2.DataS DataS_T2  
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.DataH = T2.DataH AND T1.DataO =T2.DataO AND T1.DataS = T2.DataS
WHERE T1.DataH = @DataH
AND T1.DataS = @DataS

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DataH_T1,@DataO_T1,@DataS_T1,@DataH_T2,@DataO_T2,@DataS_T2  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

      IF (@DataH_T2 IS NULL)
      BEGIN
          INSERT INTO Table2 (DataS,DataH,DataO,Result1,Result2,Result3)
          VALUES (@DataS_T1,@DataH_T1,@DataO_T1,'Test Result 1','Test Result 2','Test Result 3')
      END

      ELSE
      BEGIN
          UPDATE Table2
          SET Result1 = 'Test',
          Result2= 'test2',
          Result3= 'Test3'
          WHERE DataS = @DataS_T2 
          AND DataH = @DataH_T2
          AND DataO = @DataO_T2
      END

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DataH_T1,@DataO_T1,@DataS_T1,@DataH_T2,@DataO_T2,@DataS_T2  
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: mkRabbani, thank you for your answer. I made a test with your solution and it works. Thanks a lot ;)